# Altium Designer: Deleted mechanical layers unconditionally included in Gerber output

Tags: altium, gerber

(Altium 23.6.0)

My layout person had created a number of mechanical layers and subsequently deleted them.
That is, they are not visible in the "View Configuration --> Layers & Colors --> Mechanical layers", neither do they show up in the list of layers to potentially include in the Gerber package, when I configure that through the OutJob interface.

Though they do generate Gerbers when I run that part of the OutJob file, together with the layers I do want. They just generate completely empty Gerber files. About 10 of them, in this particular project.
But since they don't show up in the list of layers, I can't uncheck them, to prevent their generation.

Not that these empty Gerbers harm anything (I don't think), but I would still like to know if there is a way to suppress them.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like something best addressed by [official forum or tech support](https://www.altium.com/support).